# Android photo upload to facebook using graph api?

Tags: android, android-layout

i use the facebook sdk to post message to wall on my facebook account from android application , its looking fine but when i use the following code of garph api to upload the image ,

```
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();

            bundle.putString("message", "Viddygo Video Sharing");


            bundle.putString(Facebook.TOKEN,accessToken);

            bundle.putString("image", "http://simplestrength.com/wp-content/uploads/kanji_luck.png");



            String response = facebook.request("me/photos",bundle,"POST");
```

but i got the following error,

`04-26 15:01:02.005: DEBUG/UPDATE RESPONSE(9405):    {           "error":{"type":"OAuthException","message":"(#324) Requires upload file"}}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just try this

```
bundle.putString("picture", "http://simplestrength.com/wp-content/uploads/kanji_luck.png");
String response = facebook.request("me/feed",bundle,"POST");
```

for post in album..

```
bundle.putByteArray("picture", byte);
String response = facebook.request("me/photos",bundle,"POST");
```

where `byte = bytearray` of image..

Comment: it is working , i post the picture on my wall , if i want to upload the image to photo album in my facebook account what can i do.

Comment: i have the image url ,then how can i get the byte array ?

Comment: if u want upload photo in album so need byte array so first you can download and make byte array of that image and upload in album..

Comment: But it still show some error , do u have any sample for that.

Comment: http://android-apps-blog.blogspot.com/2011/04/how-to-load-image-from-web-on-android.html

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/android-how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview

Comment: this are some example of download image from URL now u need to convert that image into byte ..(search for it on stackoverflow or google)...

Comment: hi, u using newsfeed of facebook?

Comment: i use the me/photos to upload the photos to my album.not me/feed

Comment: i am getting error in response -----> **"Required permission upload_file"** while passing url as parameter

Comment: I wanted to upload the image with a title too .. can i set a title too from the android application