# Image share to facebook from android application

Tags: android, facebook

In my android application I am able to share text to facebook wall via facebook SDK for android. Can I use this to share images too directly from my application. I wanted the images to be shared from a url given through my application that changes dynamically.Any help please

Comment: Did you try to google it. what did you find?

Comment: [Already asked question][1] will help you.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5788436/android-photo-upload-to-facebook-using-graph-api

Comment: @RohitO i wanted to give title too from the android application . How can that be done..

Answer (score 1):

Visit [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/photo/) link.

The code you have to write will be something like this

```
bundle.putString("name", "name you want to give");
```

And similarly you can add another parameters to the image.

Comment: I'm not going to spoon feed him now, @look4php :D